# How to pass option tag value to SELECT2 Plug-in

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-select2

How can I pass ("option value="Value_Here") the value attribute to SELECT2 plug-in. I need the data inside the value attribute in my google map. It contains the latitude and longitude of my marker.

Code:

```
<select class="distance" id="start">
        <?php
            include "connect.php";

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblLocation";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "
                    <option value='".$row['latitude'].", ".$row['longitude']."'>".$row['branch']."</option>";
            }
            mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
</select>
```

Script for SELECT2 Plug-in:

```
 $('.distance').select2();
```

Comment: Unclear Please add more information, what you want.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd I want to pass the data inside the value attribute to SELECT2 Plugin how can I achieve that?

Comment: It means You want to add one more option and value to your existing drop-down.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd No I want to pass the data from value attribute to SELECT2 plugin

Comment: Why you need pass the data from value attribute because still, I am unclear for what you want.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd the value of my option is the coordinates for my google map i need that coordinates the value is not passing to select2

Comment: Do you want to know,  what user is selected value in dropdown?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd I know I can get the value of the select when there is no plugin

Comment: mysqli is out dated